# Set IPython Profile for QtInProcessKernelManager

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

I'm running the **IPython 2.0b1** code so that I can use the native `QtInProcessKernelManager` for embedding an IPython shell inside a Qt app. Following the example in [embedded_qtconsole.py](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/inprocess/embedded_qtconsole.py) I've got everything up and running, but I cannot figure out for the life of me how to set the IPython profile that the kernel uses. Unfortunately the doc for the 2.0 release is pretty sparse, but understandable since it's not released yet, and digging into the source hasn't been much help either.

In the old 'unofficial' way of doing it in IPython 1.12/13 you set it via the following:

```
app = IPKernelApp.instance()
app.initialize(['--profile={0}'.format(__PROFILE_NAME__)])
```

However I've tried every combination of passing varying arguments to

```
kernel_manager = QtInProcessKernelManager()
kernel_manager.start_kernel()
```

With no luck. I'm sure I'm just missing something simple, so hopefully it'll be a quick fix.

Comment: start_kernel() takes "keyword arguments that are passed down to build the kernel_cmd and launching the kernel", but I can't find further details yet.